# how can I find all fields using SFMC Query Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I wanna extract data from data extension but I don't know the fields name exactly.
so I tried `select *` and `select fields(all)` but both occurred error.
How can I know all the name of fields in SFMC Query Studio?

Answer (score 4):

In Query Studio, you have an Object Explorer on the right, where you can type in the DE name and it will show you all the fields:

[image]

Comment: It's definitely the best way to get the field names in query studio :)

Answer (score 0):

To find all fields of a data extension, you would need to find the data extension location and then go to there to extract data or copy and paste the data extension fields there for your SQL query for example.

If you don't know where to find the data extension, I would recommend using [DESelect Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deselect-search-in-salesf/ekppadhnhmemajkdbkohalhoncnfhmbm) extension for Chrome browser to find it.

In case you already know the DE location and want to quickly get all the field names. You can go to Automation Studio, create a query activity then drag the DE out to SQL query board in the step 2, it will populate all the field names by the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly * is not supported in query studio in SFMC, you must type each field manually. I find it useful to use the object explorer, and copy out the fields to excel for some formatting, then copy them back in to query.